# How to change user with authentication inside shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, shell-script

It is possible to change the user within a shell script by `su - newuser`; but what if the newuser needs authentication. How can I provide the password within the shell script?

None of the users is root.

Comment: Are you automating a non-interactive process? If so, you want `sudo`. Or do you want to prompt the user for a password? If so, can you assume that a user is logged in locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using passwords in plain text files is not recommended. However, if no security risk is involved, create an `expect` script. Expect is a scripting language designed to interact with interactive shells and it is perfect for things like authentication or automation of processes that require a user to type in different things or select different options in a shell environment.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot that I am aware of. You can schedule the job with cron for other users via Su. Besides you NEVER should put a wheel users password in a clear text file

Comment: very nice point! you're quite right!